# how to do jmeter setup for http proxy settings?

Tags: jmeter

i m trying to use jmeter to test an web application. I have windows 7, jdk7 and jmeter 2.13.

wen I followed the set up to do the proxy setting, it displays proxy already in use.. chose another port,, jvm bind..

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that default port of "8080" is busy with some other application. You can use `nestat` command to find out whether port is free and if not determine which application is using it like:

```
C:\>netstat -nao | Find "8080"

TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5072
```

In my case port "8080" is busy with the application having process id of `5072`

```
C:\>tasklist | find "5072"

tomcat7.exe                   5072 Services                   0  1,246,564 K
```

Which is Apache Tomcat 7 so JMeter Proxy clashes with Tomcat.

You can change port to any other free in JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

[image: HTTPS Test Script Recorder Port]

Alternatively you can record test script via [JMeter Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/BlazeMeter?hl=en), in that case you won't need to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, manually adding HTTP Cookie Manager and timers, etc.